# Why is Sheet.setColumnWidth not in Points? Is there a workaround?

Tags: java, excel, width, apache-poi

I'm curious why there is no implementation for [`Sheet.setColumnWidth`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth%28int,%20int%29) that accepts a `Points` parameter.

There is a method to set the height of a Row in points, which is [setHeightInPoints](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#setHeightInPoints%28float%29)

The only available method to set the width is accepting a rather weird scale, defined as

```
width = Truncate([{Number of Visible Characters} * {Maximum Digit Width} + {5 pixel padding}]/{Maximum Digit Width}*256)/256
```

This means it depends on some width of a digit, so the value used in the parameter is 
just 1/256 of what is wanted here, some straight representation of a width. In Excel itself
you set the width in Points, too.

This means behaviour of Row-height and Column-width is not symetric.

**Is there any rational reason for only having that version of `setColumnWidth`?**

This leads to serious problems, as the best I can get has a different result on every computer,
because the width which is set is depending on the users default font setting.

I believe it has something to do with displaying nicely on many different setups, as the comment of pnuts suggests. But it is only usable in a very narrow field.

At the moment I believe that there is no simple workaround for that, and I cannot find one right now. (just one that works for my case perhaps)

**Is there any good way to calculate a column width value from a desired points value?**
I.e. I want 120 points on any computer that is using the excel export functionality. **What is the width value to use as parameter here to get the wanted `points` width?**

Comment: Indeed, this is an aspect of the reason for that behaviour. But I believe POI could deliver the ubiquitous `points` scale as well.

Comment: You can ask Apache POI to calculate it for you, based on the current column's contents + stylings - did you try [Sheet.autoSizeColumn(int column)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29)?

Comment: `autoSizeColumn` does not work for me, because I have a twoline header. First line is very short, for example "abc" and second line is very long (some explanation). Cannot change that, because the customer explicitly wants it that way. So overall there is no fitting size with that two rows.

Comment: Do you know which cell's contents you want your column to be sized based on?

Comment: At the moment I know only that the first line consists of only a view characters and the second line will have a lot of text.